# Completely uninstall and reinstall Android app on update?

Tags: android, installation, alarmmanager

I want to publish a new version of my app. But I want it to reinstall again.

Like first uninstall and then install(like first time installation). Is there anyway that I can do it? Or force users to first uninstall the app?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have an app that frequently set alarm I hard coded in the app that doesn't do it more than 4 times while it should be 20. Now I changed it but when I install it again it still works for 4 times but when I delete it and reinstall it, it works. I should mention that in previous version my alarm was in intentservice but now is in broadcast receiver....

Comment: Short of changing the package name & effectively making it a new install for your app - no. Detect an upgrade & try to undo the damage done by previous versions instead. Alarms in the AlarmManager are not persisted across reboots anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign the new apk with a different key, users will hit an error when they try to upgrade an existing installation. That’s probably the easiest way to do it without changing the package name.

Answer (score 0):

As Jens said you can't do this really unless you reinstall with a different package name (not a good idea either.)  You have to detect your version and manually reset your preferences etc. if you need to.  This is a pretty annoying feature of android.  I've been developing a mapping application that has the exact same problem with storing some of the background data.

You can usually check where your preferences get created for the first time.  A lot of people do a if(preference !=null) to set them up, since in a pre-installed app you already have that preference in the bundle it will not update or generate a new one.

Try setting the preference checker to be if(preference != newValueOfPreference)

If that's not how your bundle data is generated on install you'll have to find out how it is generated and get at that hook.